# in/on a typical day

Tags: prepositions, difference

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/typical):
**(1a)** ***On** a typical day, our students go to classes from 7.30 am to 1 pm*.
My variant:
**(1b)** ***In** a typical day, our students go to classes from 7.30 am to 1 pm*.

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/typical):
**(2a)** ***On** a typical day, we receive about 50 letters*.
My variant:
**(2b)** ***In** a typical day, we receive about 50 letters*.

name of a [video](https://www.britannica.com/video/21970/Lions-activities-hunting-eating-grooming):
**(3a)** *Observe a predatory lion pride **in** a typical day of grooming, playing, hunting and eating prey, and sleeping*
My variant:
**(3b)** *Observe a predatory lion pride **on** a typical day of grooming, playing, hunting and eating prey, and sleeping*

a thread from [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/on-in-a-typical-day.3625350/) where:
**(4a)** *I do a lot of chores **on** a typical day*. - a native said it's incorrect (the reason I didn't understand)
**(4b)** *I do a lot of chores **in** a typical day*. - a native said it's correct  (the reason I didn't understand)

Which sentences are correct and which are not?
What is the difference between "*in a typical day*" and "*on a typical day*"?
When should I use "*in a typical day*" and when "*on a typical day*"?

Comment: Astralbee's answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/251634/in-the-same-day-vs-on-the-same-day?rq=1) may be helpful. We tend to use "in" when drawing attention to the length of a day.

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me, but I'm not going to use my mod hammer for this

Comment: Yes… what did Astralbee's Post in that Link leave unclear, please?